# Передача параметра из switch

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! Накануне делал функцию уменьшения размера изображения. Так вот,  никак не получается привести ее в рабочее состояние.
А именно, переменная `$source` никак не хочет передаваться из `switch` в виде 2-го параметра в `imagecopyresized`.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: source in .../functions.php on line 97

Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in .../functions.php on line 97

Notice: Undefined variable: source in .../functions.php on line 111

Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in .../functions.php on line 111
```

В чем может быть причина? Делаю на локалке.

Вот исходный код:

```
function thumImg($file) {
$ext = strtolower(strrchr(basename($file), '.'));
$prefix = 'thum_';
$th = "thum/";
// $extension = array('.jpg', '.gif', '.png');
$imgname = basename($file);
$sas = getimagesize($file);
$width = $sas[0];
$height = $sas[1];

    if ($width >= $height) {
        $newwidth = 200;
        $newheight = $height / ($width / 200);
    } else {
        $newwidth = $width / ($height / 200);
        $newheight = 200;
    }

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

    switch ($ext) {
        case '.jpg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case '.png':
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
    }
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    switch ($ext) {
        case '.jpg':
            imagejpeg($thumb, $th . $prefix . $imgname);
            break;
        case '.gif':
            imagegif($thumb, $th . $prefix . $imgname);
            break;
        case '.png':
            imagepng($thumb, $th . $prefix . $imgname);
            break;
    }
imagedestroy($thumb);
imagedestroy($source);
```

}

Очень прошу помочь советом. Гугл не дал ничего адекватного. Справка php тоже.
Так же, не могли бы вы мне объяснить функцию `imagecopyresized`, а именно, что такое 2-й параметр (Source image link resource)? То есть источник для изображения чего?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Вообще у вас switch просто не срабатывает. Перед ним сделайте `var_dump($file, $ext)` и дайте результат. А, и пример вызова. Меня терзают смутные сомненья)

Comment: Сомненья насчет чего?)

Comment: Вы дайте результат, пока рано выводы делать

Comment: string '...temp\php3C09.tmp' (length=40)

string '.tmp' (length=4)
добавилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот вам собственно и ответ: switch не срабатывает.

Почему? Потому что вы делаете тумбочку из временного файла, имеющего расширение `.tmp`

Что делаем: перед вызовом функции копируем файл по-нормальному, т.е. допустим вы получаете файл через `$_FILES['upload']`

```
$new_name = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/images/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$image = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $new_name);
thumImg($new_name);
```

ЗЫ: Доработайте функцию еще, чтобы не считать ее быдлокодом - сделайте проверку расширений(а лучше `mimetype`, все ищется в гугле) и возвращаемое значение (`true/false`), в `switch` добавьте

```
default: return false; break;
```

ЗЗЫ: картинки `image/jpeg` бывают `.jpg` и `.jpeg`

Comment: Я заметил что он не пашет).Спасибо вам Sh4dow,сам бы никак не дошел бы до этого,как только попробую дописать функцию,отпишусь что из этого вышло.)

Comment: В моем случае проверка расширений исполняет другая функция,это просто формирует thumbnail.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ и за указания на мои ошибки).Все заработало)